# Can not figure out why this will not compile

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I'm trying to understand why the following will not compile. The compiler complains on the line where CreatePresenter tries to set the View property:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sandbox.Program.MyView' to 'TView'.

I know the context of the assignment does not make sense, it's more for illustration. Any help would be great!

```
    interface IView {
    }

    class Presenter<T> where T : IView {
        public T View { get; set; }
    }

    class MyView : IView {
    }

    class MyPresenter : Presenter<MyView> {
        public MyPresenter() { }
    }

    class ViewBase<TPresenter, TView>  
        where TPresenter : Presenter<TView>, new()
        where TView : IView {

        public TPresenter Presenter { get; private set; }

        void CreatePresenter() {
            this.Presenter = new TPresenter();
            this.Presenter.View = new MyView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Must the presenter's view always be an instance of the concrete `MyView`?

Comment: @Michael - he posted it. Cannot convert type.

Comment: @BoltClock Like I said, this is for illustration purposes only. The assignment would really be to 'this'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the line:

```
this.Presenter.View = new MyView();
```

you're trying to set a `MyView` object to a property of generic type `TView` (implementing `IView`).

This is wrong because `MyView` is different from `TView` so it can't be assigned.

**EDIT:**

To expand a bit...

You *can* assign a type to its interface e.g. :

```
IView v = new MyView(); // OK !
```

but you *can't* assign an interface to one of its implementers e.g.:

```
IView v = ...;
MyView myView = v; // WRONG !
```

Here you're doing something more convoluted, something like this:

```
        IView
   _______|_______
  |               |
  |               |
TView    <--   MyView
```

That is clearly wrong.
In fact, even if `TView` and `MyView` implement the same interface, to allow this `TView` should inherit from `MyView` but that's not specified among the generic constraints, and so the compiler can't do any assumption.

Have a look also to [davy8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23822/davy8) for a clear example :)

Comment: I was about to submit my answer when this appeared with a V similar description ;) +1.

Comment: even though MyView implements IView ?

Comment: @Marco that's irrelevant because for example both int and BigInt implement IComparable, you can't set the BigInt to int.

Comment: @Yuriy ok, that makes sense. i am just learning about co/contra variance and i thought this would allow this type of code.

Comment: @Marco see my answer for a concrete example of why it can't work.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have 2 more classes:

```
class MyView2 : IView
{
}

class MyPresenter2 : Presenter<MyView2>
{
    public MyPresenter2() { }
}
```

Then you try to construct a new ViewBase with those:

```
var viewBase = new ViewBase<MyPresenter2, MyView2>();
```

In that case, in your method:

```
void CreatePresenter()
{
    this.Presenter = new TPresenter();
    this.Presenter.View = new MyView();
}
```

`this.Presenter.View` is `MyView2` which doesn't inherit from `MyView`, even though both of them implement `IView`

Answer (score 0):

`MyView` is not guaranteed to be of the same type `TView`.  You can have several implementations of `IView` that aren't `MyViews` using this generic class.

If you change `ViewBase` to the code below, it will at least compile.  I'm not sure how it will affect the behavior of your application.

```
class ViewBase<TPresenter, TView>
    where TPresenter : Presenter<TView>, new()
    where TView : IView, new()
{

    public TPresenter Presenter { get; private set; }

    void CreatePresenter()
    {
        this.Presenter = new TPresenter();
        this.Presenter.View = new TView();
    }
}
```